# Adaptive image caching based on available RAM or iOS Memory warning level

Tags: ios, memory, memory-management, didreceivememorywarning

I have an app which caches large images so that user do not wait for imageWithContentsOfFile. As a general rule I cache a previous and next image.

1) Can I make this caching adaptive based on the available memory in iPad ? If yes what should be the threshold ? Below is the function to calculate the available memory

```
-(void) report_memory {
    struct task_basic_info info;
    mach_msg_type_number_t size = sizeof(info);
    kern_return_t kerr = task_info(mach_task_self(),
                                   TASK_BASIC_INFO,
                                   (task_info_t)&info,
                                   &size);
    if( kerr == KERN_SUCCESS ) {
        Log(@"Memory in use (in bytes): %u", info.resident_size);
    } else {
        Log(@"Error with task_info(): %s", mach_error_string(kerr));
    }
}
```

2) I know there is no way to (except the private/undocumented API) know the memory level warning, otherwise it could be a good factor to determine how many pages I can cache. But just to confirm can I use them in some way.

3) Right now I am thinking of caching 3 screens (which have 6 images) and in case my ViewController receive memory warning I unload all screens except the visible one and reset number of screens to cache to 2 (4 images). But I don't found it optimized because either I am caching less than what is possible or in some conditions even loading 4 leads to crash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking to cache as much data as possible without causing the application to crash, you can always make use of the function didReceiveMemoryWarning to remove excess caches when needed. Within this function, you don't have to clear out everything. You could use it to selectively clear up enough room for the current situation and then continue caching until it fires off this warning again.

An alternative would be to start a cache routine until the warning fires. This would allow you to create a count of items that were able to be cached. Once this count is reached, you could have your caching iterations stay far enough below that count to avoid issues.

Not exactly an in-depth explanation, but these are some ideas for making use of the standard methods available that should still be able to achieve your goal.

Answer (score 0):

So after waiting for so long I am answering my question if it may be helpful for someone.

You should avoid any undocumented API to get warning level and take action based on that. The only suggested action on memory warning irrespective of level is to release as much memory as you can. 
You can use a heuristic based on report_memory function (see question) to determine how much we can cache. Although I have not performed any tests to calculate the threshold (it should be based on total RAM). I would love to see someone perform these tests and update.

The approach to reset the number of pages to cache on memory warning is working fine for my case.

Comment: You may want to attempt to request help without being rude and if you want answers, aid others in understanding you by using relevant language and less complex terminology. Your original answer did not make sense and editing a comment that is not fully understood could change the entire context.

Comment: You could have been nicer in your original comment which is now gone. Anyways thanks for your answer.

Comment: I removed it because you revised your answer in a way that no longer resembles the transcript of a spelling bee.